# Android Studio problem: Unused Java instance variable marked as used

Tags: java, android-studio, variables, variable-names

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338 (linux version). Although this problem might also appear in Intellij Idea which I have not tested. The problem is whenever I name my instance variables by certain names (like place,time,date) they are instantly marked as used right when I declare them! Below is a screenshot of the problem:[image]

Here I just opened the default Hello World project and typed some declarations. I have not touched anything in the project other than this. Imagine how much of a nightmare would be this kind of misinformation for big projects! Can anyone here solve this or suggest any workaround (other than changing names of those variables)? (And also if you feel to downvote then atleast comment first)

Comment: Is default settings change along with your theme ? or u change configuration related to java?

Comment: @Lucefer No No its just a theme and does not change anything except appearance. Every settings except that remain same. I also did not changed anything.